# unable to insert document into mongodb using scala API

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am trying to insert a document using Scala API for MongoDB but no luck yet. I am using the API to insert the data and checking it from mongo shell. Shell says no document is inserted but API does not throw any error before completing the execution. After execution is complete, I am getting this exception:

```
[cluster-ClusterId{value='n123b2h34vj23h4j2bk2jb34k', description='null'}-cluster0-shard-00-00.server.com:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00.server.com:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:215)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:201)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:220)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:201)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:430)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:191)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:301)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:74)
```

Here is my code snippet for inserting the data:

```
val mongoClient = MongoConfig.getMongoClient()
val mongoDatabase = MongoConfig.getMongoDb(mongoClient, "mydb")
val mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("mycol")

val userDocument = Document(createBsonDocument(user))

val insertObservable = mongoCollection.insertOne(userDocument)

insertObservable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
    override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Insert operation successful")
    override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Insert operation failed")
    override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Insert operation completed")
})
```

And the config for DB connection:
    package some.package

```
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient, MongoClientSettings, MongoDatabase, MongoCollection, ServerAddress}
import org.mongodb.scala.connection.ClusterSettings
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
import com.mongodb.{MongoSocketReadException, MongoSocketException}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object MongoConfig {
    def setMongoClusterConfig(): ClusterSettings = {
        val mongoClusterSettings: ClusterSettings = ClusterSettings
            .builder
            .hosts(List(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-00.server.com:27017"), 
                        new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-01.server.com:27017"),
                        new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-02.server.com:27017"))
                   .asJava)
            .build

        mongoClusterSettings
    }

    def createMongoCredentials(mongoDbName: String = "mydb", 
                               mongoUsername: String = "username", 
                               mongoPassword: Array[Char] = "password".toCharArray): MongoCredential = {
        val mongoCredential: MongoCredential = MongoCredential
            .createCredential(mongoUsername, mongoDbName, mongoPassword)

        mongoCredential
    }

    @throws(classOf[MongoSocketReadException])
    @throws(classOf[MongoSocketException])
    def getMongoClient(mongoClusterSettings: ClusterSettings = setMongoClusterConfig(),
                       mongoCredential: MongoCredential = createMongoCredentials()): MongoClient = {
        val mongoClientSettings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings
            .builder
            .clusterSettings(mongoClusterSettings)
            .credentialList(List(mongoCredential).asJava)
            .build

        // System.setProperty("org.mongodb.async.type", "netty")

        MongoClient(mongoClientSettings)
    }

    def getMongoDb(mongoClient: MongoClient,
                   mongoDbName: String): MongoDatabase = {
        getMongoClient().getDatabase(mongoDbName)
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check if any firewall blocks the port *27017* to *cluster0-shard-00-00.server.com* ?

Comment: And consider using ReactiveMongo.

Comment: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00.server.com:27017 shows that your app is not able to connect to DB. Can you check if the DB's are accessible from the machine where this code runs?

Comment: I think I had to use ssl and NettyStreamFactoryFactory. But now I am stuck somewhere else: 
 com.mypackage.myapp.operations.RegistrationTest *** ABORTED ***
   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT
   at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.java:70)
   at org.mongodb.scala.connection.NettyStreamFactoryFactory$.apply(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.scala:27)

Seems there is a conflict between two netty connection packages. Any Ideas?
FYI: I am using mongo Atlas.

Comment: Using ReactiveMongo!

Comment: hello @Mrinal did you find any solution please